# How to fill in blank cells with correct data without overwriting the data above it

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I've been trying to get this working, and I've come up with this, but it's obviously not working...

```
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


With wsJL
    Dim wsJL As Worksheet
    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")

        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        fstcell = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("AA1:AD1").Copy wsJL.Range("J & fstcell:N" & lastrow)
End With
```

This part isn't working...

```
wsJL.Range("AA1:AD1").Copy wsJL.Range("J & fstcell:N" & lastrow)
```

I'd like to know how to make it work...I've never seen a formula used this way though my google searches so I don't even know if it's possible or not.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You are missing some quotes.  `"J & fstcell:N" & lastrow` should be `"J" & fstcell & ":N" & lastrow`.  However, I believe `"J & fstcell` would be enough.  Only the first cell of the destination need be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quite get me to follow the whole way, but I think you're going for something like this:

```
wsJL.Range("AA1:AD1").Copy wsJL.Range("J" & fstcell & ":N" & lastrow)
```

Note the `&` operator probably won't work inside your string.

Comment: Ok, I didn't even notice I had a typo... thanks for that, but that being said still a no go.  Basically what I'm trying to do is take what is in cells AA1:AD1 copy to the first open cell in J all the way to N, and to end so it doesn't pass the last cell in I. So it would look as if it was pasting something like this: `wsJL.Range("AA1:AD1").Copy wsJL.Range("J22:N50)`  I hope this make sense now.

Comment: I'm not seeing that add up.  Sounds like you want `J22 = AA1`, `K22 = AB1`, `L22 = AC1`, `M22 = AD1`, but what about `N22` ?  And are you saying `J23 = AA1`, etc, for the next row also?

Comment: Sorry cell typo on my side, was meant to be `AA1:AE1`. Ok, here is what I'm trying to do. In cells A through I is data imported on a daily basis. J through N are cells that have formulas in it, or are manually adjusted. Cells `AA1:AE1` are what go into `J:N`. In cells `AA1, AC1` are formulas, in `AB1` is a conditional formatting, which can't overwrite `J`, what is in the cells prior to what is above, nor can  `AE1` replace what is in N, because people leave comments in the cells in `N`. So I need a formula that will paste what is in `AA1:AE1`, but not go past `I`. Does this make any sense now?

Comment: Here is the sheet in question I am working with, it's the first workbook. Don't mind the error, it's a false error that doesn't show up on the original document for obvious reasons. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/complex.xlsm